# Use Vue-JS custom helper functions directly in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have my helper function in VueJS, i can call it in JavaScript but cannot use it inside HTML tags. Following is my helper.js function.

```
//Helper JS file
const allowNumbers = e => {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
  // numbers   
      key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
  // Numeric keypad
      key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
  // comma, period and minus, . on keypad
    key == 190 || key == 188 || key == 109 || key == 110 ||
  // Backspace and Tab and Enter
    key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
  // Home and End
    key == 35 || key == 36 ||
  // left and right arrows
    key == 37 || key == 39 ||
  // Del and Ins
    key == 46 || key == 45)
      return true
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
}
export {
  allowNumbers
}
```

I am importing it in Vue component but its giving error of "function not defined". My Vue file is.

```
<!-- Vue component file -->
<input maxlength="4" type="text" @keydown="allowNumbers" />

<script>
import {allowNumbers} from '@/helpers'
</script>
```

**NOTE : I have updated my code, but i still need some way to directly use helper functions within HTML**

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways that I don't know how to help you. I would suggest to you to reread the Vue doc and see how to use Vue.

Comment: Hi, Why do you say that? Please explain the comment too.

Comment: @JacobGoh i have updated my code, please see it now. I still need someway to directly use helper function inside the HTML.

Comment: @HasnatSafder Can you explain what are you trying to do? Do you want to ignore certain key events? But it's on text input

Comment: Checkout https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html for event modifires

Answer (score 3):

As for your question to access and data or function from vue template Make sure that the property is ***either in the data option or listed under methods.***
Assuming we have the following helper function

```
//Helper JS file
const utilFunc = num => {
  if (num < 0) {
    return "negetive";
  }
  return "posetive";
};
export { utilFunc };
```

In yout vue component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  {{val}}
  {{proxyUtilFunc(-9)}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { utilFunc } from "@/helpers";
export default {
  name: "App",
   methods: {
      proxyUtilFunc: utilFunc
  },
  data() {
    return {
      val: utilFunc(5)
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

But as I have noticed, you are trying to render an HTML with dynamic style values which is exactly why we need **[components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)** for.

> So I highly recommend you refactor it to be spinner component on its
> own.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <i v-bind:style="{fontSize: size + 'px' }" class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "MySpinner",
  props: {
    size: {
      type: Number
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qw9w8v1o7) to experiment with.**

> NB: Consider checking out code reusability section of the official
> [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)  use [directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html), **[vue mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)** and **vue
> [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)** for code reusablity .

Comment: Thank you, please see the updated code in my question. So basically i cannot use it directly?